# Impossible to access an attribute (title) on a string variable

Tags: categories, entry, conditional

I have a Video section with a field called `videoCategory`. I'm trying to pull in the first category on the _entry.html template.

I'm pretty much following the the last example in the documentation at: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories-fields

...with this code:

```
 {% set entryCategory = entry.videoCategory.first() %}
 {% if entryCategory %}
   <h1>{% for category in entryCategory %}<a href="">{{ category.title }}</a> {% endfor %}</h1>
 {% endif %}
```

But I can't get around this error message:

> *Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a string variable ("19")*

What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

entryCategory is already a single category because of "first()". So no need for the for loop. Just {{ entryCategory.title }} should do the trick here.

```
{% set entryCategory = entry.videoCategory.first() %}
{% if entryCategory %}
    <h1><a href="">{{ entryCategory.title }}</a></h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Too simple. Only my first week with Craft, so I'm full of these little questions. Thanks jkenters!